# Spring security 4 @PreAuthorize("hasRole()") not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've been troubleshooting for the past few days and I cant seem to get the expression hasRole to work. I'm using spring-security 4.0.1

**my spring security xml**

```
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>


<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**/*.css" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/fonts/*.*" access="permitAll" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/landing" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccesHandler" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" />

    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
       <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean>
```

All my roles is stored in database and have a schema similar to the 1 in this [link](http://slackspace.de/articles/roles-permissions-with-spring-security-3/). In my custom `userDetailService` I'll load it from database. My roles values is something like this

```
PYRL-EMPPF-01
PYRL-EMPPF-02
PYRL-EMPPF-03
```

I've even tried putting prefix "ROLE_" but I cant seem get it work.

here is my sample code on how I use hasRole expression. I'm trying to use it to secure my controller methods.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/URLABC", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_PYRL-EMPPF-01')")
public ModelAndView search(HttpSession session) throws Exception {
...
}
```

I've tried `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_PYRL-EMPPF-01')")` and also `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('PYRL-EMPPF-01')")` both also not working.

Comment: Can you try @Secured({ "ROLE_PYRL-EMPPF-01" })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I manage to stumble on the answer

```
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>
```

I just need to put this spring config from my spring security xml config to spring servlet config.

here is my web.xml. previously the the config above is in application-security.xml now I move it to dispatcher-servlet.xml.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

and also instead of using `org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`. I've change it to use `org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`.

If anyone can explain the difference between the 2 ExpressionHandler class it will be great.